# 1680s-1750s England/Wales inheritance of estates through female line

Tags: wales

Is there a general rule in this period for inheriting an estate, viz:-

- If the female heir is still alive, does she inherit, jointly with her husband, who would be controlling the estate?
- If the female heir is dead, but the husband lives, does he never get his hands on the estate and it goes to their joint child?
- If their joint child is a minor, and she is dead, but the husband is alive, does he manage the estate on the behalf of his son?

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE! Which definition of estate do you mean in this question? From Oxford: 1. an extensive area of land in the country, usually with a large house, owned by one person, family, or organization. 2. all the money and property owned by a particular person, especially at death. If 1, is the estate entailed?

Comment: This is a curious thing, but I don't know! I know that when the Goughs inherited it was put into a family trust so that when the last of the Portreys died, the estate went to the Gough air, whereas Christopher Portrey bequeathed his personal property to the son and daughter of his younger sister.

But I don't have any information I can find about the Portrey inheritance from the Aubreys. Also, the trust postdates when Catherine Portrey, William Gough's wife, died, so I don't know if he would have inherited jointly with her had she lived.